# what the best way to send verify mail and reset password mail from server?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, email, vps

im using digitalOcean vps and i upload my laravel projects but i have some problem with postfix all mails come as spam.
i did all things about smtp (spf, dkim ... etc) and test on (https://mail-tester.com) and i got (9/10) score but all mails still come as spam.

whats is the best way to delivery all mails (verify, reset password ...etc) to users without third party like (mailgun ...etc).

thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use zoho mail to link your domain to zoho mail account 
if delivered mails didn't receive into inbox try to install ssl to your domain and send messages over SSL